# What would users feel comfortable to see first in navigation

Tags: navigation, menu, information-architecture, objects

Reading about object-oriented UX and audience based navigation, I am still not sure how to approach the following problem:

I am building a careers section of a web site, where I must present job/internship/training opportunities by location and by profession.

**My hypothetical flow:**

I am intuitively going for profession first - that is, on the first screen, users would see boxes with professions (this is the so called audience based navigation).

Once a user identifies with a profession and clicks on the respective box, they would see boxes for jobs/internships/trainings.

Once they choose any of those, locations would show.

[image]

---

What is your take on this, based on your experience with conducted research and theory?

Comment: The question is actually how to conduct user research. This is a very broad topic. What is your background and are you familiar with user centered design? Maybe you find this [UX Research Cheat Sheet](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ux-research-cheat-sheet/) useful.

Comment: The question is about any theoretical frameworks which may suggest in what order those pieces of information should be presented, nothing to do with how to conduct user research in general. For example, the "audience based navigation" approach would suggest that I start with professions first.

Comment: Sorry but I find these questions confusing: "Is this the correct order of presenting the navigation choices? How could I possibly know what do users care about first among those three?" - my first response is: by doing user research. But if that's not what you're after maybe you should rephrase it.

Comment: Everyone who has at least some theoretical background in UX knows that before you think of user research, you consult findings, shared experience, theories, first. The latter is what I am asking about and I think that would not need special explanation or rephrasing for a professional.

Comment: I'm only trying to help. At the stage where designers start thinking about IA at such detailed level, they should already have a good understanding of the field and the user. So my advice would be not to worry about those details yet given the early stage you are in.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a correct answer, without at least conducting user research. With all products being different, there might be room to investigate your use cases better.

You could break the information out into separate sections by bucketing the listings in separate categories, and then list the postings in an A-Z sort, something like the example below.

[image: Example of Job Posting Hierarchy]

Comment: Where does the type of engagement - job/internship/training show in this model?

Comment: That would really just be another filter that you could apply. I noticed you stated that you were going to break these into screens? I would keep them all on one, and maybe give the user the tools to filter better.

Answer (score 1):

All of the "3 levels" seem to me as one level actually.
Where you could show some sort of filter, all on same level, with Profession - Type of employment - Location, all of which should have option for multiple selection.

When you finish your prototype (either on paper with all screens drawn, or even better digital clickable version) you could just call or meet 5 - 6 people (that are closest to your audience, ideally don't have Bias towards your product or brand).

Give them intro, and ask them to perform a task (i.e. of finding all jobs for XY with contract type XY and in City XY).
Before that ask them to "think loud" about what they think during process, and explain them that you are not testing them and that there are no right or wrong answers. Observe and listen how they react and make notes.

If you see repeating problems within process for more than 1 user you probably need to iterate, if not - your design is on a good way.

Comment: Putting all in one place (so called "one level") is good for interfaces which people visit regularly and get used to the interface, and prefer all visible in one place, because they'd play with it a lot and there won't be any learning curve after the first few visits. For interfaces designated for one time visits, though, the learning curve should as easy as possible, at the expense of many clicks, if needed. As I am asking about a case where users are expected to visit once or not too often, I'd rather have the levels either in different screens or in progressive disclosure.

Comment: I agree. But also "Your users are learning design patterns from other interfaces than yours". They have already saw multiple sites with job listings and learned from there. And there its always in form of filter, which when designed properly (with i.e. appropriate icons and naming) can be self explanatory. Also "Recognition over recall" and other logic forwards in direction in always showing all options doable and changable.

Comment: "They have already saw multiple sites with job listings" - that is not necessarily true for the entire audience. There's such a segment for sure, but also have the segments of brand new computer users, elder people and people of generally low cognitive abilities, who are very slow to learn, even after going through the same UIs numerous times.